# Computing matrix norms, 2 -norms and infinity -norms

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the matrix $A = (c_1,...,c_n) $ where $c_i$ are the column vectors of $A$ and $c_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Suppose we put $c_1 = (1,...,1)$ and $c_2=c_3 = ... = c_m = (0,...,0)$. I know $||A||_{\infty} = \sup \sum (\text{rows}  \;\text{of} \; A ) = 1 $. I am unable to compute $||A||_2 = \sup_{ x \in \mathbb{R}^m } \frac{ ||Ax||_2}{||x||_2 }$. How can I compute this norm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just calculate $Ax$ you will have a clumn matrix $m\times 1$ which all elements are $x_1$, thus $||A||_2 = \sup_{ x \in \mathbb{R}^m } \frac{ ||Ax||_2}{||x||_2 }\leq\frac{ ‎‎\sqrt{m}|x_1|}{||x||_2 }\leq\frac{ \sqrt{m}||x||_2‎‎}{||x||_2 }\leq ‎‎\sqrt{m}$. Now let $x=(1,0,0,...,0)$ then $Ax=(1,1,1,...,1)$ thus $\frac{ ||Ax||_2}{||x||_2 }=\frac{ \sqrt{m}}{1 }=\sqrt{m}$ thus $||A||_2\geq \sqrt{m}$

Comment: so is it $||A||_2 = \sqrt{m} $ ?

Comment: yes, it is $\sqrt{m}$

Comment: What do you mean by inverse ?

Comment: let me wright it with detail.